# Set default language inside Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I want to set a property using Google Maps API to dynamically set a specific language to display.

I have the following script:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed"></iframe>
```

I would like to set the language such as RU.
I tried this:

```
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed&language=ru-RU"></iframe>
```

It still does not work. Can you help me?

Comment: This is very interesting, it seems that they have changed something...

Comment: How did you generate your API-KEY?

Comment: Did you tried `language=ru`?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#optional_parameters):

> language defines the language to use for UI elements and for the display of labels on map tiles. Note that this parameter is only supported for some country tiles; if the specific language requested is not supported for the tile set, then the default language for that tileset will be used. By default, visitors will see a map in their own language.

There aren't any tiles in Russian for New York City, if you pan to Russia, you will see Russian tiles.

[example map](http://geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_RU.html)